# Vaadin- Unselect radio button on double click in

Tags: java, event-handling, vaadin

Is it possible to clear or unselect the radio button(OptionGroup) in vaadin.

tell me how to catch the double click event on a radio button/already checked radio button

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It might be doable by adding a `LayoutClickListener` to the parent layout of your `OptionGroup`, and setting the value of `OptionGroup` to `null` when a double click event occurs.

Whether the above works or not (I haven't tested), I would recommend to add one more radio button to your `OptionGroup`, which represents this nothing selected case. Much more intuitive for the end used.

Or you could use checkboxes in your OptionGroup (`setMultiSelect(true)`) and in a `ValueChangeListener` remove previous selection(s) from the `OptionGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the value to null

```
radioButton.setValue(null);
```